# Writing test for pyspark udf

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am having some internal python dependency being executed inside a spark `pandas_udf` . To pass parameters we are wrapping this inside another function.

Code looks like below

```
def wrapper_fn(df, parameters):
    @pandas_udf(schema,GROUPED_MAP)
    def run_pandas_code():
        """ Importing some python library and using it """
        return pandas_df
    return df.groupby(<key>).apply(run_pandas_code)
```

I want to write a test that executes the function `wrapper_fn` . But when i write these test, i get pickle error . Can someone recommend a good way to test pyspark udf's .

Answer (score 0):

It was possible to do this eventually. The problem was with the reference to some class which `pyspark` weren't able to serialise.